# Angular bootstrap center few navbar items

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a simple navbar in which is there are multiple items i just need to center and make the last div to end.

My code

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 justify-content-center">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">WHO WE ARE</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        WHAT WE DO
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        MEDIA
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <div class="dropdown drp-user" ngbDropdown placement='auto'>
      <a href="javascript:" ngbDropdownToggle data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="icon feather icon-settings"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right profile-notification" ngbDropdownMenu>
        <div class="pro-head">
          <img src="assets/images/user/avatar-2.jpg" class="img-radius" alt="User-Profile-Image">
          <span>{{userTitle}}</span>
          <a href="javascript:" class="dud-logout" title="Logout" (click)="logout()">
            <i class="feather icon-log-out"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="pro-body">
          <li *ngIf="user?.userTypeId == this.userTypeIdEnum.ADMIN"><a href="javascript:" class="dropdown-item"
              routerLink="/manageprofile"><i class="feather icon-user"></i> Manage Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:" class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/auth/change-password"><i
                class="feather icon-lock"></i> Change Password</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

In image i have marked red item which i need to do center if i am wrapping it to div then its not showing in a row.

Comment: Replace class `ms-auto` with `mx-auto` for `navbar-nav`.

Comment: @CY tried not working

Comment: You have wrapped it in the `nav` tag, right?